# Botones de siguiente y anterior en formulario/consulta de php

Tags: php, html

He conectado mi base de datos a mi pagina html, la hice en forma de consulta utilizando etiquetas `<input>` de texto, los cuales solo muestran un dato de cada columna en la tabla (son 5), son al rededor de 1810 registros y necesito que los botones me muestren el dato siguiente o el anterior, al igual que los dos botones para ir al primer registro y para el ultimo, de ante mano gracias.

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="Jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","u677991360_pined","exanime123");
mysqli_select_db($conexion, "u677991360_calnd");

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM BDCALENDARIO";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$return_arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $row_array['cct'] = $row['CCT'];
  $row_array['centroTrab'] = $row['CENTRO_DE_TRABAJO'];
  $row_array['municipio'] = $row['MUNICIPIO'];
  $row_array['modalidad'] = $row['MODALIDAD'];
  $row_array['calendario'] = $row['CALENDARIO'];

  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
//esta linea es la que te imprime todo el json 
//echo json_encode($return_arr);
//Agrego la linea para guardarlo en una variable
$objJSON=json_encode($return_arr);
?>
<script src="Jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  action='#' id="formu">
  CCT: <input type='text' size='30' id='cct' />
  <br/> Centro de Trabajo: <input type='text' id='centroTrab' />
  <br/> Municipio: <input type='text' size='30' id='municipio' />
  <br/> Modalidad: <input type='text' id='modalidad' />
  <br/> Calendario: <input type='text' id='calendario' />
  <br/>
  <button id="ini">Inicio</button>
  <button id="atr">Atras</button>
  <button id="sig">Sig</button>
  <button id="fin">Final</button>

</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

y así esta el Script js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var objJSON=JSON.parse(<?= $objJSON ?>);
  var i=0;
  var tam=objJSON.length;

  $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
    $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
    $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
    $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
    $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);

  $("#ini").click(function(){
    i=0;
    $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
    $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
    $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
    $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
    $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);

  });
  $("#sig").click(function(){

    if(i<tam-1){
      i++;
      $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
      $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
      $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
      $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
      $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);
    }

  });
  $("#atr").click(function(){
    if(i>0){
      i--;
      $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
      $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
      $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
      $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
      $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);
    }
  });
  $("#fin").click(function(){
    i=tam-1;
    $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
    $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
    $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
    $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
    $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);



  });

});
#prim,#ulti{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Esta sería la base de datos en PHPMyAdmin:

[image: Imagen]

Y esta es mi pagina que aun no le doy estilo pero al menos muestra los datos: http://pineda-calendar.hol.es/

y como puedes notar muestra el primer registro de la base de datos(2DJN0160K), el botón serviría para que se muestre el siguiente(23DJN058Q) y de igual forma con el botón "anterior" regrese o muestre un registro anterior a ese.

Comment: Por que no usas una tabla?, el problema con lo que quieres hacer es que o vas a tener que estar haciendo llamdas a la bd cada que quieras un nuevo registro. O manejar AJAX para estar haciendo consultas a la bd y que se te muestren en los inputs. Tambien puedes hacer un JSON de de la consulta  y puedes irlo iterando con Jquery. Depende de lo que necesites y tengas que hacer

Comment: y puedes usar JS?, el problema con php es que es un lenguaje que se compila en el servidor, por tanto una vez que se compila y se manda al navegador ya no puede cambiarse a menos que se refresque la pantalla. pero pues eso no es de estas epocas. podemos pasar la consulta a JS y como este es interpretado por el navegador este si puede hacer cambios en la vista permitiendonos cambiar entre los datos.

Comment: ok, podrias poner una captura de la info que vas a poner, de la bd por ejemplo?

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es **paginar resultados**.
Yo hice uno con POO / PHP tiempo atras:
[http://mac-mix.blogspot.com.es/2015/10/php-poo-paginador-de-resultados.html](http://mac-mix.blogspot.com.es/2015/10/php-poo-paginador-de-resultados.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que recibes bien todos los datos de la BD y que las columnas de esta tienen el nombre de los input. cuando recibas los datos puedes pasarlos a un JSON. Con este array de información podemos trabajar con JQuery (js) y hacer cosas interesantes. entonces veamos por partes lo que hay que hacer.

```
<?php
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","Ususario","Contraseña");
 mysqli_select_db($conexion, "BasedeDatos");
 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM BDCALENDARIO";
 $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
?>
```

suponiendo que lo anterior esta correcto y nos da en `$query` la info que necesitamos. podemos pasarlo a un JSON de la siguiente forma.

```
$return_arr = array(); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $row_array['cct'] = $row['CCT'];
  $row_array['centroTrab'] = $row['CENTRO_DE_TRABAJO'];
  $row_array['municipio'] = $row['MUNICIPIO'];
  $row_array['modalidad'] = $row['MODALIDAD'];
  $row_array['calendario'] = $row['CALENDARIO'];

  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$objJSON=json_encode($return_arr);
```

Con esto ya tenemos un json, ahora solo debemos pasarlo a JQuery, supon que lo que nos regresa es algo como esto.(ignora los valores,por que no se cuales son)

```
[

{
    "ctt": "1",
    "centroTrab": "Manzana",
    "municipio": "100",
    "modalidad": "1",
    "calendario": "Manza"
  },
  {
    "ctt": "1",
    "centroTrab": "pera",
    "municipio": "300",
    "modalidad": "1f",
    "calendario": "Mzana"
  },
  {
    "ctt": "1",
    "centroTrab": "NAranja",
    "municipio": "200",
    "modalidad": "1g",
    "calendario": "Maa"
  }
]
```

usa vez con esto podemos trabajar con JQuery de la siguiente manera

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  //supon que ya tienes tu variable que guarda el json en php 
  //solo harias lo siguiente
  //var objJson=JSON.parse(<?= "'".addslashes($objJSON)."'" ?>);
  //para emular esto voy a poner el json aqui en crudo.
  
  var objJSON=JSON.parse('[{"cct":"1","centroTrab":"Manzana","municipio":"100","modalidad":"1","calendario":"Manza"},{"cct":"2","centroTrab":"pera","municipio":"300","modalidad":"1f","calendario":"Mzana"},{"cct":"3","centroTrab":"NAranja","municipio":"200","modalidad":"1g","calendario":"Maa"}]');
  
  //ahora ya lo manipulamos dependiendo del boton que apretamos
  var i=0; //vamos a usar un iterador para saber en que registro estamos
  var tam=objJSON.length; //tamaño de registros en el JSON
  
  $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
    $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
    $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
    $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
    $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);
  
  $("#ini").click(function(){
    i=0;
    $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
    $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
    $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
    $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
    $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);
    
  });
  $("#sig").click(function(){
    
    if(i<tam-1){
      i++;
      $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
      $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
      $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
      $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
      $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);
    }
  
  });
  $("#atr").click(function(){
    if(i>0){
      i--;
      $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
      $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
      $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
      $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
      $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);
    }
  });
  $("#fin").click(function(){
    i=tam-1;
    $("#cct").val(objJSON[i].cct);
    $("#centroTrab").val(objJSON[i].centroTrab);
    $("#municipio").val(objJSON[i].municipio);
    $("#modalidad").val(objJSON[i].modalidad);
    $("#calendario").val(objJSON[i].calendario);
    
    
  
  });

});
```

```css
#prim,#ulti{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  action='#' id="formu">
  CCT: <input type='text' size='30' id='cct' />
  <br/> Centro de Trabajo: <input type='text' id='centroTrab' />
  <br/> Municipio: <input type='text' size='30' id='municipio' />
  <br/> Modalidad: <input type='text' id='modalidad' />
  <br/> Calendario: <input type='text' id='calendario' />
  <br/>
  <button id="ini">Inicio</button>
  <button id="atr">Atras</button>
  <button id="sig">Sig</button>
  <button id="fin">Final</button>

</form>
```

y bueno con eso tendrias el efecto que quieres, es cuestion de ir agregando cosas para que se vea mas llamativo.

La funcion `addslashes($str)` sirve para escapar todos los caracteres especiales que pudiera haber el el json. y le concatené una comillas simples para que lo interpretará como un String.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56098/discussion-on-answer-by-luis-botones-de-siguiente-y-anterior-en-formulario-consu).